# how to convert boolean column to 0 and 1 by using pd.get_dummies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert all boolean columns in my pandas dataframe into 0 and 1 by using pd.get_dummies. However, the boolean values stay the same after the get_dummies function.

For example:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame([  
        ['green' , True],   
        ['red'   , False],   
        ['blue'  , True]]) 
tmp.columns = ['color',  'class'] 
pd.get_dummies(tmp)  
# I have also tried pd.get_dummies(tmp, dtype=int), but got the same output
```

I got:

```
   class  color_blue  color_green  color_red
0   True           0            1          0
1  False           0            0          1
2   True           1            0          0
```

but I need:

```
   color_blue  color_green  color_red  class_True  class_False
0           0            1          0        1        0
1           0            0          1        0        1
2           1            0          0        1        0
```

update:
My dataframe includes numeric data so convert all columns in the dataframe into string may not be the best soluion.

Comment: Do you check second solution in answer?

Comment: @jezrael Yes it works. I'm thinking are there any convenient way to do this if I have many boolean columns in the dataframe

Comment: Added solution to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For processing boolean columns convert them to strings (here are converted all columns):

```
print (pd.get_dummies(tmp.astype(str)))
   color_blue  color_green  color_red  class_False  class_True
0           0            1          0            0           1
1           0            0          1            1           0
2           1            0          0            0           1
```

Of convert only boolean:

```
print (pd.get_dummies(tmp.astype({'class':'str'})))
   color_blue  color_green  color_red  class_False  class_True
0           0            1          0            0           1
1           0            0          1            1           0
2           1            0          0            0           1
```

You can create dictionary only for boolean columns:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(tmp.select_dtypes('bool').columns, 'str')
print (pd.get_dummies(tmp.astype(d)))
```

Comment: The third solution works well! thx

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) the dtype parameter controls the type of the dummy variable columns that are generated. So, in your case you could just specify `dtype=int` to get the result:

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame([  
        ['green' , True],   
        ['red'   , False],   
        ['blue'  , True]]) 
tmp.columns = ['color',  'class'] 
pd.get_dummies(tmp, dtype='int')  


 class  color_blue  color_green  color_red
   0   True           0            1          0
   1   False          0            0          1
   2   True           1            0          0
```